# How to download bzip2 sources for linux?

Tags: bz2, bzip

I used to download http://www.bzip.org/1.0.6/bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz
But now http://www.bzip.org/ does not exists anymore.

Comment: http://distfiles.gentoo.org/distfiles/bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz http://gentoo.ussg.indiana.edu/distfiles/bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz http://gentoo-distfiles.mirrors.tds.net/distfiles/bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz https://gentoo.osuosl.org/distfiles/bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz https://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/gentoo/distfiles/bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz

Comment: That was what gentoo is using at the moment using my selected mirrors.

Comment: @karelv. Please consider rewording your question? We cant do much about missing/broken links. If you are still wondering about compiling sources, add some more context/information.

Comment: Gentoo says the homepage is https://sourceware.org/bzip2/

Comment: BTW, this probably should have been asked at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: So I rephrase my question, it is indeed a download question, and @drescherjm give me an answer that helps me out!

Comment: drescherjm did not gave you the right homepage: it's an old page from 2002 for version 1.0.2, while the redhat for instance is using 1.0.6 released in 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source tarball is now at sourceforge.net .

The linux from scratch project also keeps a copy at http://anduin.linuxfromscratch.org/LFS/bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz